# Why JavaScript code execute second part sometimes

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am draw background on canvas and also small images on that background. But sometimes, background draw on small images. Why ?

JavaScript code -

```
var canvasupdate = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctxupdate = canvasupdate.getContext("2d");
var background = new Image();
background.src = sitePath + "ATOM/chapter1/book/" + `bgimagename`;
background.onload = function() {
    ctxupdate.drawImage(background, 0, 0); // set background image 
};



var imageobj = new Array();
for (var d = 0; d < calloutImageArray.length; d++) // getting small images in array
{
    imageobj[d] = new Image();
    (function(d) {
        imageobj[d].src = sitePath + "ATOM/chapter1/book/" + calloutImageArray[d];
        imageobj[d].onload = function() {
            ctxupdate.drawImage(imageobj[d], calloutImageArrayX[d], calloutImageArrayY[d], calloutImageArrayW[d], calloutImageArrayH[d]);
        };
    })(d);
}
```

In above code, background image code should be execute first then call out image(small image) code execute but some time execute small images code and then background image code why?

Answer (score 0):

All the images are loaded asynchronously. So sometimes the small images are loaded (and drawn) before the background image. Please take a look into e.g. Network tab in Chrome in which order the resources load is done.

The simplest solution for this problem is to move the loading of small images into the callback function for `load` event of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

The onLoad function runs asynchronously. That means JavaScript will continue to run the rest of your code and will run the callback function when the background image is loaded. That's why your second part of the code runs first. So instead try to add your code inside the onload function like this:

```
var canvasupdate = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctxupdate = canvasupdate.getContext("2d");
var background = new Image();
background.src = sitePath + "ATOM/chapter1/book/" + `bgimagename`;
background.onload = function() {
    ctxupdate.drawImage(background, 0, 0); // set background image 
    var imageobj = new Array();
    for (var d = 0; d < calloutImageArray.length; d++) // getting small images in array
    {
         imageobj[d] = new Image();
         (function(d) {
            imageobj[d].src = sitePath + "ATOM/chapter1/book/" + calloutImageArray[d];
            imageobj[d].onload = function() {
             ctxupdate.drawImage(imageobj[d], calloutImageArrayX[d], calloutImageArrayY[d], calloutImageArrayW[d], calloutImageArrayH[d]);
           };
         })(d);
    }
};
```

that way you can be sure that the background will be set first and then your small images. Note that I didn't try your code to check if it does what you want, I just rearranged the code blocks to show you the logic and why does not run as you would expect.
Hope it helps